# Review queue privilege is achieved at different rep?

Tags: support

I am somewhat confused as to why accessing review queues is given at 350 rep on Vim.SE, but on other sites such as Stack Overflow, it's not awarded until 500 rep. (And on SE Community/Meta it's not awarded until 2000 rep).

I would think there is a template as to which rep privilege is awarded at each rep level, and that it would be the same for all sites.

Are the rep privileges decided on a per-site basis? How are they decided and why is there a difference?

I've thoroughly read the SE Meta post about reputation and also the one on Vim.SE and couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beta sites have lower limits, the idea being that beta sites have smaller communities, and thus need lower limits to still have enough users to take care or the review queues and various other moderation tasks.

These limits will be raised when this site graduates.

See [Reputation requirements compared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58587/166789) at meta SE, as well as [/help/privileges](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

Comment: Ah, excellent. That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. It's interesting that when the limits are raised, it's possible to lose some privileges.

Comment: @Tim Yeah, for private beta the limits are even lower, and myself (as well as a bunch of other people) lost some privileges when we went to public beta ;-) There have been a few suggestions to allow people to keep their privileges, but none of them have been particularly well received IIRC.